# Moodle integration with website with the use of web services

Tags: moodle, openerp-7

I already installed Moodle on Ubuntu with the use of database phpMyAdmin. I just want to integrate a new website with Moodle with the use of web services in Moodle.

But the problem is that I searched on YouTube about web services but they show Config Moodle to use web service and connect with OpenERP version 7. Since don't have Open ERP, is it necessary to have Open ERP. MY basic need is that I want a website that linked with Moodle website so I can fetch data or courses.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Provide the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: If it's urgent, you should respond to the comment Daenarys left for you. The rest of us are waiting to see that, too. As it currently stands, your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. phpMyAdmin is an application to work with databases, not a database itself. moodle does have web services, which (as a non-moodle user) seem to be pretty well documented on their website. OpenERP doesn't even exist anymore; since version 8 it's called Odoo; you probably you should start with a more recent version. Whether you actually need OpenERP depends on what you're trying to do. Show some code.

Comment: No, i just want a external api which fetches the data from moodle and i knw it can be done with the use of web services but prblm is how??

Answer (score 0):

Moodle has several webServices, the most I've used are core_users_create_user, edit, delete, depending on what you want you can acces certain info of moodle...
[moodle webServices](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services_Roadmap)

Comment: No, i just want a external api which fetches the data from moodle and i knw it can be done with the use of web services but prblm is how??

Comment: i have a token of my service but what is the use of this token..... i mean my boss said to me just create a external api which fetches the data from moodle and i searched on net and found web servics and then folllow the steps and created a token but now what next.. i mean what i have to do next...